# Regular expressions for Notepad++ to search } \r }

Tags: regex

I have something like this in my file:

```
    material { M_AD26 }
  }
  }
  union {
```

I would like to replace these two single consecutive brackets with one to yield:

```
    material { M_AD26 }
  }
  union {
```

In Notepad++ I tried something like (})\r(\s)(}) with different number of \s but never got it right to find these repeated brackets. Many thanks for help.

Comment: Does `\}\s+\}` to replace with `}` solve the issue?

Comment: Partially... I have to replace } } in the empty lines with one }, but I also have lines without }, so replacing M_AD26 } } with } does not help. I need to replace only 2nd and 3rd line with single }

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me:

[image]

Regex:

```
(^\s*\}\s*)\1
```

Replace:

```
\1
```

Hope it helps.